# Powershell Get Child Item Exclude doesn't work in current directory

Tags: powershell, filter, file-extension, get-childitem, write-host

As I mentioned in question, this seems like bug in Powershell engine.

When I try to print the files in the current directory(where the said powershell script is also present) by excluding some file-types(extensions), it doesn't print anything. For eg. below codes print contents of Current Folder in the Powershell console:

```
gci
gci -pa .
```

Both the above codes print the directory contents as below:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                     
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                     
-a----       20-09-2020     22:37      835799796 file1.mkv                                                                      
-a----       20-09-2020     22:25            148 file1.srt                                      
-a----       23-09-2020     04:53            357 scriptv1.ps1                                                           
-a----       20-09-2020     22:25            678 file1.txt
```

But when I run below code, it doesn't print anything, when it must print file1.txt:

```
$excluded = @('*.mkv','*.mp4','*.srt','*.sub','*.ps1')
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | Write-Host { $_.FullName }
```

Can anyone assist figuring out why is it happening and how to get what I mentioned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `-Exclude` with `Get-ChildItem` is not intuitive. To get consistent results with `Get-ChildItem`, you must qualify your path with `\*` or use the `-Recurse` switch. If you do not care to recurse, you can just use `Get-Item` with a `\*` qualifying the path.

```
# Works but includes all subdirectory searches
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Exclude $excluded
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Exclude $excluded -File
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Exclude $excluded -File -Recurse

# Best results for one directory
Get-Item -Path .\* -Exclude $excluded
```

---

The reason recursion should be used is because `-Exclude` values are applied to the leaf of `-Path` value first. If any of those exclusions match your target directory, then it will be excluded and prevent any of its items from being displayed. See below:

```
$path = 'c:\temp'
# produces nothing because t* matches temp
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude 't*'
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing exclusion parameter correctly in your `gci` example, but where it may fail in your console silently is processing the results into `write-host` as it doesn't process the `{ .. }` script block as a `foreach-object` would do for the individual items. The silent error should be:

> Write-Host: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the
> command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the
> input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
> pipeline input.

With this respect, the correct short `foreach-object` pipeline notation would be:

```
$excluded = @('*.mkv','*.mp4','*.srt','*.sub','*.ps1')
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

Regarding the silent errors, I assume your session is set to be `Silent`, which you can check with the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable. If you wish to see all errors - in a non-blocking mode, you can set this to `Continue` eg:

```
$ErrorActionPreference='Continue'
```

Relevant PS7 pages and examples:

- `Write-Host` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7
- `Foreach-Object`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7
- `Preference` Variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | Write-Host { $_.FullName }` shouldn't fail silently unless all children in your directory are excluded by your filter.

If you try to run `Get-ChildItem | Write-Host { $_.FullName }` in a non empty directory, it should a throw an error similar to this one:

```
Write-Host: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

The reason is that `Write-Host` can't take an array as parameter (and we know that's an array by doing `(Get-ChildItem).GetType()`).

Therefore, you need to first iterate over the elements of the array using `ForEach-Object` or one of its aliases: `foreach` or `%`.

```bsh
$excluded = @('*.mkv','*.mp4','*.srt','*.sub','*.ps1')
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName }
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | foreach { Write-Host $_.FullName }
Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excluded | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```